# Can I call JS function from document.formID.submit();?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, function

I want to know if I can call a JS function from a `submit()`.

```
document.quotationForm.submit(function() {
  loading('show');
});
```

My `loading()` function contains the jQuery mobile loading code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to bind/attach the event listener to the form. Your code will trigger an actual submission of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do it like that - add an event listener instead:

```
document.quotationForm.onsubmit = function() {
    loading("show");
};

document.quotationForm.submit(); //Will run your code as well as submitting the form
```

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you could use a onclick reference in the submit button

```
<form>
    <formStuff></>
    <btn type="submit" onclick="someJSFunction()"></>
</form>
```